# Reader/Writer Locks in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking

I'm looking for a good reader/writer lock in C++. We have a use case of a single infrequent writer and many frequent readers and would like to optimize for this. Preferable I would like a cross-platform solution, however a Windows only one would be acceptable.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Newer versions of [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread.html) have read/write locks (1.35.0 and later, apparently the previous versions did not work correctly).

They have the names [`shared_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock), [`unique_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.shared_lock), and [`upgrade_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.upgrade_lock) and operate on a [`shared_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex).

Comment: We're on 1.34.1, that might be a reason to move up :)

Comment: The thread library underwent a massive overhaul from 1.34 -> 1.35 so be aware of this when upgrading. Some breaking API changes were made, but they wont affect most people very much. The new version is more in line with the proposed C++0x library interface, which is a good thing in the long run.

Comment: We don't use most of the threading library to heavily, but we do use it for our locks. I did bust into the details to specialize lock_ops in one place so I could use scoped_lock with my type. I agree that in the long run we want the more standard implementation.

Comment: If you're lucky enough to have C++14 or C++17 available, you can also use [`shared_timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) and a matching [`shared_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock).

Answer (score 66):

Since C++ 14 (VS2015) you can use the standard:

```
#include <shared_mutex>

typedef std::shared_mutex Lock;
typedef std::unique_lock< Lock >  WriteLock; // C++ 11
typedef std::shared_lock< Lock >  ReadLock;  // C++ 14

Lock myLock;

void ReadFunction()
{
     ReadLock r_lock(myLock);
     //Do reader stuff
}

void WriteFunction()
{
     WriteLock w_lock(myLock);
     //Do writer stuff
}
```

For older compiler versions and standards you can use **boost** to create a read-write lock:

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_mutex Lock;
typedef boost::unique_lock< Lock >  WriteLock;
typedef boost::shared_lock< Lock >  ReadLock;
```

Comment: This looks like this will still starve the write thread given tons of read threads and one write thread.

Comment: You don't need 3 separate locks -- std::shared_mutex already supports ReadWriteLock functionality by itself. To acquire an exclusive (writer) lock, use ".lock()", to acquire a shared (reader) lock use ".lock_shared()"

Comment: @GavinRay Yes, but with using those structs, you get  wrapping RAII objects that will ensure proper resource management and ensure that the locks are actually released in the end of the scope.

Comment: Oh I see, so they're alternatives to using std::lock_guard in each function where you acquire locks?

Answer (score 38):

Using standard pre-tested, pre-built stuff is always good (for example, Boost as another answer suggested), but this is something that's not too hard to build yourself.  Here's a dumb little implementation pulled out from a project of mine:

```
#include <pthread.h>

struct rwlock {
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t read, write;
    unsigned readers, writers, read_waiters, write_waiters;
};

void reader_lock(struct rwlock *self) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&self->lock);
    if (self->writers || self->write_waiters) {
        self->read_waiters++;
        do pthread_cond_wait(&self->read, &self->lock);
        while (self->writers || self->write_waiters);
        self->read_waiters--;
    }
    self->readers++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&self->lock);
}

void reader_unlock(struct rwlock *self) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&self->lock);
    self->readers--;
    if (self->write_waiters)
        pthread_cond_signal(&self->write);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&self->lock);
}

void writer_lock(struct rwlock *self) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&self->lock);
    if (self->readers || self->writers) {
        self->write_waiters++;
        do pthread_cond_wait(&self->write, &self->lock);
        while (self->readers || self->writers);
        self->write_waiters--;
    }
    self->writers = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&self->lock);
}

void writer_unlock(struct rwlock *self) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&self->lock);
    self->writers = 0;
    if (self->write_waiters)
        pthread_cond_signal(&self->write);
    else if (self->read_waiters)
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&self->read);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&self->lock);
}

void rwlock_init(struct rwlock *self) {
    self->readers = self->writers = self->read_waiters = self->write_waiters = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&self->lock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&self->read, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&self->write, NULL);
}
```

`pthreads` not really being Windows-native, but the general idea is here.  This implementation is slightly biased towards writers (a horde of writers can starve readers indefinitely); just modify `writer_unlock` if you'd rather the balance be the other way around.

Yes, this is C and not C++.  Translation is an exercise left to the reader.

### Edit

Greg Rogers pointed out that the POSIX standard does specify `pthread_rwlock_*`.  This doesn't help if you don't have `pthreads`, but it stirred my mind into remembering: [Pthreads-w32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) should work!  Instead of porting this code to non-`pthreads` for your own use, just use Pthreads-w32 on Windows, and native `pthreads` everywhere else.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you reimplemented pthread_rwlock_(rd/wr)(un)lock on top of pthread_mutex_t instead of just using the native pthread API.

Comment: Because I could / for fun.  This project was a bit of a testbed for various locking facilities of mine.  Also, it's useful as a demonstration now, right?

Comment: Unfortunately NOT an implementation that is usable. Potential busy Spin wait here:  while (self->writers || self->write_waiters); Plus you gave a C solution to a C++ question.

Comment: It doesn't spin: the `while` modifies the `do pthread_cond_wait` on the line immediately above it.  There are no exceptions in C.  (True, I don't handle error conditions, but those aren't exceptions.)

Comment: In the reader_unlock function, you signal the writers, even if there are readers currently reading the data. It is better to add to your condition
 if (self->readers == 0 && self->write_waiters) ...

Comment: Like I mentioned, "This implementation is slightly biased towards writers (a horde of writers can starve readers indefinitely); just modify `writer_unlock` if you'd rather the balance be the other way around."

Comment: I'm trying to make a different point here. If there are readers still reading, there is no point in signaling the writers, as the writers will not start working anyway, and just catch the lock and take useless time. This is a matter of minor inefficiency, not of priority.

Comment: What do mean there is no point?  A new writer can happily take the lock even when there are readers waiting for the lock as long as nobody is actually holding the lock, and proceed to do work.  If you have a continuous stream of readers and don't want occasional short writers to be blocked by them, this is the better balance.

Answer (score 15):

Whatever you decide to use, benchmark your work load against simple locks, as read/write locks tend to be 3-40x slower than simple mutex, when there is no contention.

Here is [some reference](http://www.zeroc.com/doc/Ice-3.3.0-IceTouch/manual/Threads.32.10.html)

Comment: That's interesting, we definitely are benchmarking everything.

Comment: links is invalid

Comment: To read more on this: C++ Concurrency in Action 2nd. ed. by Anthony Williams, chapter 3.3.2 and later 8-th.

Comment: Simple test shows that r/w locking might really be slower in some cases: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dce6e59b0f01d513

Answer (score 10):

Edit: The MSDN Magazine link isn't available anymore. The CodeProject article is now available on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32685/Testing-reader-writer-locks and sums it up pretty nicely. Also I found a new MSDN link about [Compound Synchronisation Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810427.aspx).

There is an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163405.aspx) about reader-writer locks on MSDN that presents some implementations of them. It also introduces the Slim reader/writer lock, a kernel synchronisation primitive introduced with Vista. There's also a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/testing_rwlocks.aspx) about comparing different implementations (including the MSDN article's ones).

Comment: My experience with the slim rw lock is that it's super fast compared to the ones based on mutexes and signals.

Comment: The annoying thing is that to use it you have to write run-time OS detection and use function pointers or a virtual class to select a locking strategy. Not practical to ignore XP yet.

Comment: yes, you're right, Zan. Just wanted to mention it, in case someone finds the question and can use it.

Comment: @vividos: You have a broken MSDN link.

Answer (score 10):

C++17 supports [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) . It is supported in [MSVC++ 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt420524.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and 2017.

Comment: And in C++14, there is the [`shared_timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_timed_mutex) and a matching [`shared_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock).

Answer (score 4):

Intel Thread Building Blocks also provide a couple of rw_lock variants:

http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/

They have a spin_rw_mutex for very short periods of contention and a queueing_rw_mutex for longer periods of contention. The former can be used in particularly performance sensitive code. The latter is more comparable in performance to that provided by Boost.Thread or directly using pthreads. But profile to make sure which one is a win for your access patterns.

Comment: Er, not that I would necessarily recommend bringing in all of TBB just to get rw_locks.

Comment: Instead of choosing the variant based on "particularly performance sensitive code", the choice should be based on the average duration the lock will be held. If the lock is held only for the reading of a few integers and released afterwards, then spin will be appropriate. Otherwise queueing will be appropriate.

Comment: @rwong I agree completely. I intended to convey the appropriate time windows in the previous sentence and perhaps made it sound more wishy-washy than it is. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend the [ACE library](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html), which provides a multitude of locking mechanisms and is ported to various platforms.

Depending on the boundary conditions of your problem, you may find the following classes useful:

- `ACE_RW_Process_Mutex`
- `ACE_Write_Guard` and `ACE_Read_Guard`
- `ACE_Condition`

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but I don't think I can get the ACE libraries into our build right now. I've used them in the past and they are great.

Comment: Anything that has to do with ACE is bad. it's an ancient code base, poorly documented and impossible to get into. Avoid infecting your code with it at any cost.

Comment: I completely agree with @shoosh: Even the link provided in the answer 404s :-( The project I'm working on (which started in the late 17th century) uses it, so I'll have no other choice but to make do, but for any moderately fresh code: Stay away from ACE at all costs.

Comment: On the subject of how contemporary ACE is, see also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/992069/217844) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8368493/217844) SO question.

Answer (score 3):

[Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/thread.html) has since release 1.35.0 already supports reader-writer locks. The good thing about this is that the implementation is greatly cross-platform, peer-reviewed, and is actually [a reference implementation for the upcoming C++0x standard](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/211600441?pgno=3).

Comment: Yeah, almost -- but Boost.Thread being the basis for C++0x threading wasn't part of the accepted answer above. Consider this additional information. :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/ReaderWriterLock.aspx

Here is a good and lightweight implementation suitable for most tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple-Reader, Single-Writer Synchronization Lock Class for Win32 by Glenn Slayde

http://www.glennslayden.com/code/win32/reader-writer-lock

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <shared_mutex>

class Foo {
 public:
  void Write() {
    std::unique_lock lock{mutex_};
    // ... 
  }

  void Read() {
    std::shared_lock lock{mutex_};
    // ... 
  }

 private:
  std::shared_mutex mutex_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy Sun's excellent [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).  It includes features such as optional fairness, lock downgrading, and of course reentrancy.

Yes it's in Java, but you can easily read and transpose it to C++, even if you don't know any Java.  The documentation I linked to contains all the behavioral properties of this implementation so you can make sure it does what you want.

If nothing else, it's a guide.

Comment: Java and C++ are soo different in style thats probably not a good idea. Java threading builtin to the language C++ does not. The code (directly translated) is not exception safe.

Comment: That's completely untrue.  In fact, Java's intstruction reordering rules are *more* permissive than most C++ compilers, which means it's *safer*.  Your statement that "threading is in the language" is moot because the thread behavior is clearly defined as a standard "mutex" and "lock" system which all C++ threading systems that I've ever used also have, so the translation would indeed be simple.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of exception-safety.  Java doesn't use RAII idiomatically, and C++ doesn't have `finally`, so a direct translation from Java to C++ is a bad idea in the presence of excepions.