# what the statement means? 'The current thread owns an exclusive lock on m'

Tags: multithreading, boost

Can someone please explain me what the statement (under precondition) means in below text and what significance it has in threading?

This text is available at [boost threading tutorial page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.unique_lock.constructor_adopt)

```
unique_lock(Lockable & m,boost::adopt_lock_t)


Precondition:
**The current thread owns an exclusive lock on m.**

Effects:
**Stores a reference to m. Takes ownership of the lock state of m.**

Postcondition:
owns_lock() returns true. mutex() returns &m.

Throws:
Nothing.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pre (before) condition: a condition that must be true before calling the function.

In this case the Lockable object "m" must be *already locked by the current thread*.

What this particular constructor does is adopt the lock. It takes ownership of it away from another owner. The unique_lock object will unlock the Lockable when it is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really is about the semantics of Boost's "unique_lock()".

Here's a good explanation:

> [boost::unique_lock vs boost::lock_guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731027/boostunique-lock-vs-boostlock-guard)
>
> The currently best voted answer is good, but it did not clarify my
>   doubt till I dug a bit deeper so decided to share with people who
>   might be in the same boat.
>
> Firstly both lock_guard and unique_lock follows the RAII pattern, in
>   the simplest use case the lock is acquired during construction and
>   unlocked during destruction automatically. If that is your use case
>   then you don't need the extra flexibility of unique_lock and
>   lock_guard will be more efficient.
>
> The key difference between both is a unique_lock instance doesn't need
>   to always own the mutex it is associated with while in lock_guard it
>   owns the mutex. This means unique_lock would need to have an extra
>   flag indicating whether it owns the lock and another extra method
>   'owns_lock()' to check that. Knowing this we can explain all extra
>   benefits this flags brings with the overhead of that extra data to be
>   set and checked -
>
> 1) Lock doesn't have to taken right at the construction, you can pass the flag std::defer_lock during its construction to keep the mutex
>   unlocked during construction.
>
> 2) We can unlock it before the function ends and don't have to necessarily wait for destructor to release it, which can be handy.
>
> 3) You can pass the ownership of the lock from a function, it is movable and not copyable.
>
> 4) It can be used with conditional variables since that requires mutex to be locked, condition checked and unlocked while waiting for a
>   condition.