# Node pointed by pointer not have changes

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, boost

I have a problem, I have this pointers in my thread code and they are being modify in there, but when it return to the main the changes are not there like this:

Threads

```
void threaded_function(Model_factory &mf, ppa::Node *root) { // threads management

try { // n try...
```

Main

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ...
```

In the main I am creating a node root, then in threads the node is being given sequences and has a bool that changes to true like:

```
ppa::Node *root;
```

And in the threads is working (a thread group) I can get and set that bool as I wish, but when the thread group finishes with join all (this is boost) the pointer root give me 0 on this line

```
cout << root->has_sequence() << endl;
```

After this goes on and the node is again filled with something, so what I want to ask is why is my node pointer not reflecting the changes in the threads, is it design or am I wrong (likely the second) and what should I do a global root node will that fix my issue, but why?

Comment: Can you reduce it to a *minimal* but complete example that reproduces the problem perhaps? I'd try running and studying something smaller, but currently that's too big, missing a `main()` and dependent on external things we can't see. Have you tried running it in something like helgrind?

Comment: yep I know is a lot, the problem is that I don't know where it is the race-cond, no I have not tried I will, nope since I don't know I don't think I can reduce it.

Comment: I have read it, but unfortunately with out knowing where is the cause I don't think I can.

Comment: the main is not needed it has a lot of thing extra, the threads are there.

Comment: This is a LOT of code. A multitude of thread checkers and analysers exists out there - just use one, e.g. Intel Thread Checker or Sun/Oracle Thread Analyzer.

Comment: thanks I did not know those I will. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a race condition, you have to suspect that you are accessing critical sections unlocked. I notice that you are manually locking and unlocking your mutex variable. This could lead to errors in your code. For instance, this construct looks particularly alarming:

```
for (int i = 0; i < deque_done.size(); i++) {

    tuple_compare(deque_done.at(i));

    result_mutex.unlock();

}
```

Instead of locking and unlocking manually, you may consider using `boost::recursive_mutex` and `boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock` to manage lock acquisition and release.

```
boost::recursive_mutex result_mutex;

void foo () {
    boost::recursive_mutex::scoped_lock lock(result_mutex);
    //...
}
```

If you really insist on designing a recursive algorithm that allows reentrancy from multiple threads, perhaps you can make use of a `boost::shared_mutex`, and `boost::shared_lock`/`boost::upgradeable_lock` for the read lock, and `boost::unique_lock`/`boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock` for write access. [You can follow this link for an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989816/315052)

Comment: how will that go, can you put a example of this. (:

Comment: @user1423656: I added a link for the `shared_mutex`, and a simple example for `recursive_mutex`. Regards

Comment: Well if anyone is interested it was this line, after putting it after for it works fine, thank you, like this for (int i = 0; i < deque_done.size(); i++) {
tuple_compare(deque_done.at(i));} result_mutex.unlock(); . (: