# How to obtain an exclusive lock *first* and then downgrade to shared without releasing the lock

Tags: c++, boost-thread, boost-mutex

Stack Overflow has several [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795/example-for-boost-shared-mutex-multiple-reads-one-write) where a function obtains an *upgradeable* lock **first** and *then* obtains exclusive access by upgrading. My understanding is that this *can* cause deadlocks if not used carefully since two threads may both obtain the upgradeable/shared lock and then both attempt to upgrade, at which point neither can proceed because the other has a shared lock.

What I want is to obtain the exclusive lock first and then downgrade to a shared lock without releasing the lock completely. I cannot find an example of this. Any ideas?

Comment: I may be out of date with the cool kids, but I thought the usual pattern is to try the upgrade and, if it fails, release the lock entirely and start all over again. Obviously this has its drawbacks, but a deadlock isn't one of them :-)

Comment: Two threads cannot obtain an upgradeable lock. Only one upgradeable lock may be held at any time. That's what makes it upgradeable: it blocks on the upgrade until the current shared locks have been released.

Comment: @Ben, how is that different from a unique_lock?

Comment: It's different in that you can have an upgradeable lock while others have a shared lock. You cannot have a unique lock while others have a shared lock.

Comment: So I can just use the existing examples and immediately upgrade after obtaining the upgradeable lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost offers this functionality through the [UpgradeLockable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable) concept. The method you are looking for is [`unlock_and_lock_shared()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable.unlock_and_lock_shared).

An implementation of this concept is provided by the [`upgrade_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.upgrade_mutex) class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the proper way to do this using lock adapters should be something like this:

```
boost::shared_mutex mtx;

void exclusive_to_shared( )
{
    boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > unique_lock( mtx );

    // The lock here is exclusive.

    boost::shared_lock< boost::shared_mutex > shared_lock( std::move( unique_lock ) );

    // The lock here is shared.
}
```

There's an explicit conversion defined from `unique_lock`'s RV refs to `shared_lock` which calls the `unlock_and_lock_shared( )`. See [this e-mail thread](http://lists.boost.org/threads-devel/2008/04/0364.php) and [the source](https://github.com/boostorg/thread/blob/boost-1.61.0/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp#L564).