# Memory models at simple RWLock-like synchronization pattern

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, atomic, nonblocking

I implemented simple lock pattern based on `TATAS-lock` extended by signed counter. It's looks like `RWLock`, but it's not TRUE `RWLock`. Writers do not block each other, but block readers. Same for readers. Writers and readers have the same priorities. (I do not know the name of this pattern.) I used new built-ins `__atomic`, which implemented in gcc-4.7 or clang. [6.52 Built-in functions for memory model aware atomic operations](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html)

```
 void lock1(int *lock_ptr) {
        int lock;
        do {
            lock = *lock_ptr;
            if(lock > 0)
                continue;
        } while(false == __atomic_compare_exchange_n(lock_ptr, &lock, lock - 1, false, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED));
    }

    void unlock1(int *lock_ptr) {
        __atomic_add_fetch (lock_ptr, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL);
    }

    void lock2(int *lock_ptr) {
        int lock;
        do {
            lock = *lock_ptr;
            if(lock < 0)
                continue;
        } while(false == __atomic_compare_exchange_n(lock_ptr, &lock, lock + 1, false, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED));
    }

    void unlock2(int *lock_ptr) {
        __atomic_sub_fetch (lock_ptr, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL);
    }
```

It's looks correct but i am not sure about memory models. Is it correct to use  `__ATOMIC_RELAXED` for `failure_memmodel` and `__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL` for `success_memmodel` at `__atomic_compare_exchange` or it's must be strong `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` even at `__atomic_sub_fetch` and `__atomic_add_fetch` or another model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example for boost shared\_mutex (multiple reads/one write)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795/example-for-boost-shared-mutex-multiple-reads-one-write)

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't ask about mutual-based RWLock example. Code in my question is lock-free algorithm based on atomic operations. So, my question - how use memory models for __atomic built-ins to get better performance.