# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::shared_mutex' to 'const boost::shared_lock<Mutex> &'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, boost

I am just trying to implement [this answer about mutexes with over 100 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820461/607407). All I did was copy paste the code, so that my class reads (simplified) like this:

#### `mymutexclass.h`

```
class MyMutexClass {
public:
    void write( uint32_t id, const std::string &str );
    std::string read( uint32_t id ) const;

private:
    boost::shared_mutex _access;
    std::map<uint32_t, std::string> strings;
};
```

#### `mymutexclass.cpp`

```
void MyMutexClass::write( uint32_t id, const std::string &str ) {
    boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > lock(_access);
    strings[id] = name;
}
std::string MyMutexClass::read( const uint32_t id ) const {
    boost::shared_lock< boost::shared_mutex > lock(_access); // ERROR HERE
    if( strings.count( id )>0) 
        return strings.at(id);
    else
        return "No value.";
}
```

And I get an error, only for the **read** mutex line:

```
error C2664: 'boost::shared_lock<Mutex>::shared_lock(const boost::shared_lock<Mutex> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const boost::shared_mutex' to 'const boost::shared_lock<Mutex> &'   D:\... path ...\mymutexclass.cpp
```

I am completely lost in the error - what's the difference between the types it complains about? I mean these, from the error:

- from `const boost::shared_mutex`
- to `const boost::shared_lock<Mutex> &`

And what am I doing wrong? That linked answer was upvoted 100 times, so I guess it's really likely to be correct.

Comment: "That linked answer was upvoted 100 times, so I guess it's really likely to be correct." it's almost 6 years old, though.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yeah, I said *likely*. But anyway, if there's a problem we might need to find it and fix it because it's top for reader/writer mutex solutions on google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your method has a `const` signature, you are not allowed to change the mutex state, hence you are not allowed to lock it. Changing the mutex to `mutable` should fix the error:

```
mutable boost::shared_mutex _access;
```

Comment: That was indeed it, respect for noticing such a little thing. You saved me hours of trouble.