# Programm terminating "std::bad_alloc" after some time

Tags: c++, boost-thread, bad-alloc

I wrapped my mind around this, yet can not find the error. Could anyone help me where I did bad programming. 
One `boost::thread` receives `strings` over a socket, splits them to `vector<string>` and sorts them into the right variable inside `shared class`. Other threads read from there. I tried to make it thread safe via mutex as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795/example-for-boost-shared-mutex-multiple-reads-one-write). 
I appreciate any help, even small hints :)
This is how the program terminates:

```
Looping...<enter to exit>
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And this is the corresponding file. It is entangled with [ROS](http://www.ros.org/), but that part shouldn't be the verdict.

```
class shared
{
public:
    shared() : count(0) {/*emp. body*/ } //constructor

    void setvec(vector<string> &strVec, int type){

        boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> uniqueLock(lock);

        switch(type) {
        case 1: typ1acc = strVec; setsensor[0] = true; break;
        case 2: typ2mag = strVec; setsensor[1] = true; break;
        case 3: typ3 = strVec; setsensor[2] = true; break;
        }/**/
    }
    vector<string> getvec(int type) {
        boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        switch(type) {
        case 1: tmp = typ1acc; break;
        case 2: tmp = typ2mag; break;
        case 3: tmp = typ3; break;
        }
        return tmp;
    }
private:
    boost::shared_mutex mtx;
    vector<string> tmp;
    vector<string> typ1acc;
    vector<string> typ2mag;
    vector<string> typ3;
};

shared c; //class object
```

Class is called from multiple boost::threads:

```
    //socket function which sorts vectors into shared class
    //this happens from one boost::thread 
    int type; //key sort by sensor type 
    vector<string> strVec;
    c.setvec(strVec,type);

    //multiple boost::threads call this to read the vectors
    //this happens from multiple boost::thread 
        strVec = c.getvec(type);
```

Comment: Are you sure ALL of that code is needed reproduce the problem - it seems awfully long...

Comment: Ok I  will try to track it further down and then edit the post.

Comment: You might also want to add how long "some time" is before the program terminates. You copy a lot of `vector<string>`s, which eventually could cause memory fragmentation.

Comment: Termination time approx. 4 minutes . Thank you this is a good idea. I suspect the tmp vector as you mention copying, as multiple threads enter the function getvec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue with having `tmp` outside the function is that the mutex destructor will (or can) run before the copy operation from `tmp` to the permanent variable resulting in a small window where `tmp` can be overwritten and cause a potential data race.

You can see this if you create simple fake mutex/string classes that show when each of them is being run. The code at the end outputs the following for me (VC++ 2015):

```
CSimpleString Raw Constructor (g_tmp)
CSimpleString Raw Constructor (result)
CFakeMutex Constructor
CSimpleString Copy Raw Operator (TestFunction)
CSimpleString Copy Constructor (TestFunction)
     CFakeMutex Destructor
     CSimpleString Copy Operator (TestFunction)
CSimpleString Destructor (TestFunction)
Result = TestFunction
```

with the important lines indented showing that your mutex is destroyed/freed before the important copy takes place. If you put `tmp` inside the function the order of operations doesn't appear to change but since `tmp` is a local variable there is no potential data race that can occur.

Very basic code for testing this is below.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

class CFakeMutex 
{
public:

    CFakeMutex() 
    {
        printf("CFakeMutex Constructor\n");
    }

    ~CFakeMutex()
    {
        printf("CFakeMutex Destructor\n");
    }
};


class CSimpleString 
{
public:

    CSimpleString() {
        printf("CSimpleString Empty Constructor\n");
    }

    CSimpleString(const char* pString) : m_String(pString) {
        printf("CSimpleString Raw Constructor (%s)\n", pString);
    }

    CSimpleString(const CSimpleString& String) : m_String(String.m_String) {
        printf("CSimpleString Copy Constructor (%s)\n", String.m_String.c_str());
    }

    ~CSimpleString()
    {
        printf("CSimpleString Destructor (%s)\n", m_String.c_str());
    }


    CSimpleString& operator=(const CSimpleString& Src)
    {
        if (&Src == this) return *this;

        printf("CSimpleString Copy Operator (%s)\n", Src.m_String.c_str());

        m_String = Src.m_String;
        return *this;
    }

    CSimpleString& operator=(const char* pString)
    {
        printf("CSimpleString Copy Raw Operator (%s)\n", pString);

        m_String = pString;
        return *this;
    }

    std::string m_String;

};

CSimpleString g_tmp("g_tmp");



CSimpleString TestFunction()
{
    CFakeMutex Mutex;
    CSimpleString local_tmp("local_tmp");

    //local_tmp = "TestFunction";
    //return local_tmp;

    g_tmp = "TestFunction";
    return g_tmp;

}

int main()
{
    CSimpleString result("result");

    result = TestFunction();

    printf("Result = %s\n", result.m_String.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Bo Persson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson) pointed me into the right direction. I put the `vector<string> tmp` into the function where its used and it runs stable.

```
    vector<string> getvec(int type) {
        boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mtx);
        vector<string> tmp; //moved into the function
        switch(type) { ...}}
```

I cannot explain why, but it runs stable. Would be great if someone could extend on this.