# c++ socket udp and tcp on unix and windows

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

can you recommend me a good c++ library(or implementation) for udp socket (multicast) and tcp
working on unix / windows system?
tnx

Comment: @Erik: That looks like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

**Description**

Portable networking and other low-level I/O, including sockets, timers, hostname resolution, socket iostreams, serial ports, file descriptors and Windows HANDLEs.

Comment: i have use one multicast socket for to send packets and some tcp socket.
use a library as asio is good? i think to something most light..

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Adaptive Communication Environment](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). This SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992069/ace-vs-boost-vs-poco) asks about the pros and cons of three different C++ networking libraries.

If you already depend on Boost, you might as well stick with boost::asio. ACE is quite a large library.