# C++ Library with http 1.1 response caching support

Tags: c++, networking, http-caching

I am working on a project where I need to communicate with a server using a network library in C++. Currently im using POCO/Net

Is there any C++ library that has support for **response caching**, authentication, HTTP and HTTPS similar to the [Java version](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=github%20droidnetworking&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fsogeti%2FDroidNetworking&ei=NLZnUeDSIsaC4ASskYHYBg&usg=AFQjCNFSGmJF0WpWHUnO3Ge8e6Jrq5om9Q&bvm=bv.45175338,d.bGE)?

Greatful for help!

Comment: I don't know if it meets all your requirements, but might want to check out [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/).

Comment: And of course there's [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992069/ace-vs-boost-vs-poco

Comment: The above don't seem to mention caching, can you please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wwwlib seems to provide the kind of persistant cache you are after and is http 1.1 compliant according to [W3lib](http://www.w3.org/Library/User/Using/Cache.html). I have not yet tried it though, it seems very low level in comparison to POCO. Someone else might have a simpler library...

Comment: I was looking for something with a bit higher level.