# What were the major differences between just::thread and poco::thread or Intel Threading Building Blocks

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am ready to build my c++ project with a solid thread library.
I do not know exactly  which library to adopt ,just::thread, poco::thread or intel threading building blocks.

I used the visual studio 2010 , and the project may need  the cross-platform compatibility in the future. The thread library of the native visual studio appeared in visual studio 2012, certainly could not crossed the platform.

The visual studio 2012 add new STL headers: , , , , , , , and . please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293(v=vs.110).aspx.

Although  is the standard header, It could certainly not be compatible for linux!

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992069/ace-vs-boost-vs-poco) is interesting for you.

Comment: you can also consider C++11 threads... (just::thread should be very close to the standard threading facilities, maybe more than your compiler's implementation, depending on the compiler you use)

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ has a solid thread library so why don't you just use it?
I don't use any library from your list but it seems that only TBB has some advantage over standard C++(it has tasks and it has concurrent containers). 
One more library to consider, if you can stick with Windows only: [PPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx)

Comment: I used the visual studio 2010 , and the project may need the cross-platform compatibility in the future

Comment: from vs2012, •Support for new STL headers: <atomic>, <chrono>, <condition_variable>, <filesystem>, <future>, <mutex>, <ratio>, and <thread>. please refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293(v=vs.110).aspx. By the way , the <thread> of vs2012 can certainly not cross the platform.

Comment: By the way, you are just wrong. `the <thread> of vs2012` is standard C++ header.