# Easiest implement pattern 1 writer - multiple readers with boost library

Tags: c++, boost

I develop a module with multiple threads and one Cache in std::map. Some times I need to update cache. In that time all readers must wait, while I do update map.
How can I do this synchronization with boost library?
P.S.: some time ago in Boost was read_write_mutex. But in current releases of Boost it missed.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > will `shared_mutex` replace `read_write_mutex`?
>
> Yes.
>
> ...
>
> Basically `unique_lock<shared_mutex>` will give you a write lock,
>   `shared_lock<shared_mutex>` will give you a read lock, and
>   `upgrade_mutex<shared_mutex>` will give you a read lock than you can upgrade by
>   transferring ownership (with move) to a `unique_lock<shared_mutex>`.

http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2008/01/132656.php