# Mutex lock on write only

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, mutex

I have a multithreaded C++ application which holds a complex data structure in memory (cached data).

Everything is great while I just read the data. I can have as many threads as I want access the data.

However the cached structure is not static.

- If the requested data item is not available it will be read from database and is then inserted into the data tree. This is probably also not problematic and even if I use a mutex while I add the new data item to the tree that will only take few cycles (it's just adding a pointer).
- There is a Garbage Collection process that's executed every now and then. It removes all old items from the tree. To do so I need to lock the whole thing down to make sure that no other process is currently accessing any data that's going to be removed from memory. I also have to lock the tree while I read from the cache so that I don't remove items while they are processed (kind of "the same thing the other way around").

"Pseudocode":

```
function getItem(key)
   lockMutex()
   foundItem = walkTreeToFindItem(key)
   copyItem(foundItem, safeCopy)
   unlockMutex()
   return safeCopy
end function

function garbageCollection()
   while item = nextItemInTree
      if (tooOld) then
         lockMutex()
         deleteItem(item)
         unlockMutex()
      end if
   end while
end function
```

What's bothering me: This means, that I have to lock the tree while I'm reading (to avoid the garbage collection to start while I read). However - as a side-effect - I also can't have two reading processes at the same time anymore.

Any suggestions?

Is there some kind of "this is a readonly action that only collides with writes" Mutex?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look into [read-write-lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read/write_lock_pattern).

You didn't specify which framework can you use but both [pThread](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems//index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/rwlocks.htm) and [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c) have implemented that pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The concept is a *"shared reader, single writer"* lock as others have stated.  In Linux environments you should be able to use [`pthread_rwlock_t`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_rwlock_init.html) without any framework.  I would suggest looking into [`boost::shared_lock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.shared_lock) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a [reader-writer lock](http://google.com/search?q=rwlock).  The idea is you can acquire a lock for "reading" or for "writing", and the lock will allow multiple readers, but only one writer.  Very handy.

Comment: There is also a queuing principle, so that if a writer ask for access it won't have to wait for a period of non-read, but will delay future read-requests until it has obtained its access and executed its work.

Answer (score 1):

In C++17 this type of access (multiple read, single write) is supported directly with [std::shared_mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex). I think this was adopted from boost::shared_lock. The topic is also described with an example in Anthony Williams's C++ Concurrency in Action.
https://livebook.manning.com/book/c-plus-plus-concurrency-in-action-second-edition/chapter-3/185.

The essential bits are:

- use std::shared_lock on reads where shared access is allowed

  - existing shared_locks don't prevent a new shared_lock from locking
- use std::unique_lock on update/write functions, where exclusive access is needed

  - will wait until all existing shared reads complete, as well as other writes
  - precludes any other reads or writes while locked