# How to set read lock and write lock in directshow application?

Tags: c++, locking, directshow

To apply a general lock, I can do this:

CAutoLock(CCritSec * plock)

But how can I set read and write lock respectively?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c) post talks about using reader-writer locks.

Comment: For directshow, there's already pretty nice locking primitives built-in, so I'd steer clear of any home-brewed/third-party stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use two separate locks...it might be possible otherwise tho.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have two separate CCritSec objects:

```
CCritSec writeLock, readLock;

void Blah::SomeMethod()
{
    CAutoLock writeAutoLock( &writeLock );
    ...
}

void Blah::SomeOtherMethod()
{
    CAutoLock readAutoLock( &readLock );
}
```

You can also lock without the auto-lock class, but I wouldn't recommend it unless your functions/methods are short and there's no possible way you'd forget to unlock.