# Counted semaphore in Linux?

Tags: c++, unix, semaphore

Are there any counted semaphores in Linux?

What I'm wanting to do is keep track of how many readers a resource has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[POSIX semaphores](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man7/sem_overview.7.html)

---

You might also consider the [Boost C++ Libraries](http://www.boost.org/).  Boost has a bunch of different threading and synchronization related components, including an abstraction for semaphores, and also a good implementation of the ReaderWriterLock.  [Check out this SO post, regarding Boost ReaderWriterLock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c).

Comment: Good choice. I would do the same.  ;)