# C++ Multithread functions with inclusive and exclusive in Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, windows, linux, multithreading

**Linux**

I have two functions: `functionA` and `functionB`

These two functions can be ran multithreaded, which:

1. There is at most one `functionA` can be ran at a time
2. There may be many `functionB`(s) can be ran at a time
3. `functionA` and `functionB` are exclusive, i.e if `functionA` is being excuted
   then `functionB` must wait until `functionA` finishes, and if there is any instance of `functionB` 
   is being executed then `functionA` must wait until **all instances** of `functionB` finish.

Could you please show me how to implement this using pthread in Linux? I tried many ways but it seems not clear enough.

**Windows**

How would I accomplish the same thing in Windows using C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reader/Writer Locks in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boost to create a read-write lock:

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_mutex Lock;
typedef boost::unique_lock< boost::shared_mutex > WrtieLock;
typedef boost::shared_lock< boost::shared_mutex >  ReadLock;

Lock myLock;


void ReadFunction()
{
    ReadLock r_lock(myLock);
    //Do reader stuff
}

void WriteFunction()
{
     WriteLock w_lock(myLock);
     //Do writer stuff
}
```

Comment: Sound amazing :-) I did not try but if this works then I think I would go this way. BWT, I rarely use boost library, is there any disadvantage if I am to apply boost anyway? Thanks @Yochai

Comment: Most of boost's libraries are just templates. So there's no extra dlls attached. And the library is pretty well optimized.

Comment: is there any reason you have posted this identical answer on three other old (2 to 3 years old) questions at the same time you posted it here? This is not the way SO is supposed to work, you don't just paste cookie-cutter answers around.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [reader/writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock).  That wikipedia article has links to a number of implementations.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what need to focus. Anyway I would appreciate any more details :-)

Answer (score 1):

For both of them you will want to take a look at [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html) (which will be available as std::thread in most major C++ compliant standard libraries). This will allow you to accomplish it on both Linux and Windows.

What you are looking for is a mutex. A mutex can only be locked by a single thread and until that thread unlocks the mutex it is the only one that is allowed to execute. See the [synchronisation chapter in the Boost.Thread documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html).

Comment: A mutex is not the solution, because as you noted, a mutex can only be owned by a single thread, and the question requires "Many functionB(s) can be ran [sic] at a time"