# vector copying and multi-threading : how to ensure multi-read even if occasional writes may happen?

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, mutex, boost-mutex

```
Pseudocode:
Function1_vector_copy () {
vectora = vectorb;
}
Function2_vector_search() {
find k in vectora;
}
```

The program is multi-threaded. While many threads may search , vector copying is done only by a single thread but at occasional times. The problem is whatever it may, vector_search should not fail. Vector_copy can be deferred but vector_search should not be. Its a no delay, no failure pattern. The problem is the shared variable vectora which has to be persistent, so that vector_search is not failed at all. What is an optimal way in achieving this ?

Edit :

[Using an answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c)

```
boost::shared_mutex _access;

Function1_vector_copy() {

  // get upgradable access
  boost::upgrade_lock lock(_access);

  // get exclusive access
  boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock uniqueLock(lock);
  // now we have exclusive access

  vectora.swap(vectorb);
}

Function2_vector_search() {

  // get shared access
  boost::shared_lock lock(_access);

  // now we have shared access

  find k in vectora ;

}
```

> If a thread with upgradable ownership tries to upgrade whilst other
>   threads have shared ownership, the attempt will fail and the thread
>   will block until exclusive ownership can be acquired.
>                                               [--boost-documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable)

The trick is the vector copy is done asynchronously and it will happen after exclusive ownership is acquired. So vector copy does eventually happen but deferred and indeed vector copy is also a non-failure operation but delayed which is okay for me. There will be a lock somehow for synchronization and we will block for a milli second atleast. But the advantage of using this swap will result in lower time of that making it negligible.

Comment: Looks like you only need a *write* lock to guard the copying. But then again, you'll need the write lock anyway for any type of read access.

Comment: Does that the search will never fail ? What happens when the copying happens and there has to be a search too. Won't the search fail ? Even I started with lock but it will happen to be opposite of what I'm thinking to achieve.

Comment: The standard multi-read-single-write idiom: *Everyone* has to wait for the write lock. You just have to design it so that the write lock will never be held for very long (e.g. make the entire copy first, and only swap the buffer pointer while locked, etc.).

Comment: What if my priority is the read and write(as it happens once at the start, the second write when it may once for may be 1000 reads) can be delayed or deferred. Its just that I would like to prioritize the read and make it as a non-failure operation at all times.

Comment: Use [read-write lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock).

Comment: I read about the shared mutex and shared locks from boost but was a bit confused on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function1_vector_copy () 
{
    VectorType tmp = vectorb;

    rwLock.acquireWrite();
    swap(tmp,vectora);
    rwLock.releaseWrite();
}
```

The rest is left as an exercise for the reader.

UPDATE:  Summarizing the comments below...

First of all I should make clear that the original `swap(...)` call above was intended as pseudo-code, not necessarily to be taken literally.  I didn't know exactly what `VectorType` was (and technically still don't).  I assumed that you would intend on doing as efficient a swap() as was possible.  It was pseudo-code after all...

In any case, `std::swap()` is specialized for all container types in the C++ standard library.  So if `VectorType` is actually `std::vector<UDT>`, then `swap(tmp,vectora);` should be both optimal and work without modification (relying on Koenig lookup to resolve the symbol).

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `swap` is virtually instantaneous.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Won't swap operate in linear time resulting in no difference to a normal copy construction ?

Comment: @King No. The swap is virtually instantaneous, roughly equivalent to swapping one pointer for another. If you're concerned, you can do a pointer swap yourself. `NewSharedPtr=new ...; lock(); oldSharedPtr=sharedPtr; sharedPtr=newSharedPtr; unlock(); delete oldSharedPtr;`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So vector swap is different to the STL swap ?

Comment: @King : I'm not sure I understand your question. But a class that doesn't have an efficient `swap` method shouldn't have one at all. If you're using a vector class that doesn't, get a new one. (Or just do the pointer swap yourself.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the STL swap is a copy construction and it seems vector swap is the pointer exchange as u mentioned. Good point and the explanation by DXM is what I was seeing about. implementing the pointer swap was what I was thinking to do but then its already present.

Answer (score 2):

I think mcmcc's idea wasn't too far off, but instead generic std::swap() which will perform vector copy, you should be able to use std::vector::swap().  Functionally vector's swap function works identically to generic one, but it is much faster since it simply exchanges few pointer/size variables and doesn't actually do element copies.  So your lock will only be around for few assembly instructions.

If that's still too long (at which point, you might want to review your design), another alternative is to have a circular list of vectors which never replace each other. Instead have another pointer which references the "active" vector.  When you need to modify that collection, initialize the next vector in the circle and when initialization is done, update the pointer. With this solution, there's no locks at all.  One instant your readers are using one vector, the next instant they are using a different vector.

Downside of the second solution is that it will definitely require more memory and it's a little bit unpredictable.  I guess you could declare your "active" vector pointer *volatile* which would force the CPU to ensure cache is synchronized every time the pointer value is read, otherwise, there's some non-deterministic element where multiple CPU cores might be looking at different snapshot of main memory.  Also without any kind of synchronization, how do you ensure that other threads are done with the vector which is about to be blown away?  And if you do any kind of synchronization, you are back RW lock.

Although I think you could get the second alternative to work and with some tweaking relatively stably... probably. My first instinct would be to go with RW lock and vector::swap().

**UPDATE:** Actually, I just reread the specs and looks like STL does specialize global std::swap specifically for containers, including std::vector.  So even when calling global function, complexity is O(1).  mcmcc's answer works.

So we put this guessing to rest, I just wrote a little bit of code and stepped through it with debugger. Here's my application code:

```
std::vector< int >      a, b;

for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    a.push_back( i );
    b.push_back( i * 10 );
}

std::swap( a, b );
```

and here's what's inside the call to global, generic version of std::swap:

```
template<class _Ty,
class _Alloc> inline
void swap(vector<_Ty, _Alloc>& _Left, vector<_Ty, _Alloc>& _Right)
{   // swap _Left and _Right vectors
_Left.swap(_Right);
}
```

As you can see generic std::swap template function, which in generic mode does the copy constructor thing, has been specialized specifically for vectors.  And internally it simply delegates all the work to std::vector::swap(), which as we established is a faster variant.

Comment: I have tried to implement that on a circular list based but obviously there has to be an update for which we will require the lock. So it seems like a trade-off for a milli-seconds of blocking for search at some point of time. +1 for justifying Swap because I was under the impression of std::swap which operates in linear time which doesn't make any difference to me. But it seems std::vector::swap() might be faster. But is it really different from normal swap and what order does it operate on ?

Comment: @King: here's some more info on vector::swap(): http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t698329-vector-swap-time-complexity.html. Basically it's O(1) operation which just involves copying 9 pointer values.  Normal std::swap invokes copy constructors, so in your case you'd definitely want to avoid that. And I think you need to give modern CPU some credit. In 0.9 milliseconds you can get 20 rows out of a SQLite database. You are talking about ~30 assembly instructions here which would probably get inlined.

Comment: @King: then again, I think with large enough rotating list (if no locking is that much more important over 50x memory usage), you could get away with a complete no lock solution.  Might need to introduce few interlocked counters here and there.  Technically should be doable if you are up for a challenge.... I wouldn't do it :)

Comment: That does the work. vector swap is the pointer exchange and not like the normal swap :) great. I was thinking to implement the pointer exchange but then its good that there is a different swap which is really performant.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/  -- says generic does copy construction and the swap in vector is pointer exchange.

Comment: @King: yes, GENERIC version will do constructors, but as I mentioned, global std::swap is overridden for all normal STL collections.  Update the answer with debugging details to show you that std::swap<vector>() simply calls std::vector::swap() to perform the actual work.