# new expression evaluation order (pointer assignment)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
Class* p = nullptr; //global var
```

This code executed by thread 1:

```
p = new Class;
```

This code executed on thread 2:

```
if (p != nullptr) ...; // does the standard gurantee that the pointer will be assigned only after object is constructed ?
```

My question is does the standard enforce when `p` will be assigned to point to allocated memory ?
Example 1:

- new expression call operator new
- `p` is assigned to point to newly allocated memory
- `Class`'s c`tor is invoked and allocated memory is passed to it

Example 2:

- new expression call operator new
- `Class`'s c`tor is invoked and allocated memory is passed to it
- `p` is assigned to point to newly allocated memory

Comment: Why don't you put a sleep inside constructor and see yourself, and share the knowledge gained? :)

Comment: According to http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf, the answer is "no" : you may have `p` pointing to allocated storage before the object has been constructed in said storage.

Comment: There is no guarantee (in fact your example invokes undefined behaviour). This is precisely one of the reasons why p must be an atomic variable. The default ordering constraints of an atomic variable will also guarantee that the constructor is complete before being assigned to p. Herb Sutter's Atomic Weapons talk does a very good job of explaining this behaviour.

Comment: Have a read about double locking pattern, the papers on it go into great length explaining why this does not work.

Comment: @AlexanderBalabin Yep I've read about the locking patters, most of the examples I've seen for the double check locking pattern do the following: `Class* tmp = new class;` and after construction `pClass = tmp`; that why I've asked this question.

Comment: Related to [Is it necessary to lock an array that is *only written to* from one thread and *only read from* another?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24682518/1708801)

Answer (score 6):

According to the standard, if these operations in two threads aren't synchronized, the behavior is undefined.

C++11 draft N3337,

[intro.multithread]/4:

> Two expression evaluations *conflict* if one of them modifies a memory location (1.7) and the other one
>   accesses or modifies the same memory location.

[intro.multithread]/21:

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads,
>   at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in
>   undefined behavior.

The corresponding quote from C++14 is essentially the same.

---

As for the execution order of `p = new Class;`, it's like in your Example 2, because first `new Class` is evaluated, and then assignment happens (provided the constructor of `Class` or `operator new` didn't throw an exception).

[expr.ass]/1:

> In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
>   computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.

Comment: Okay, what about if we leave the second thread aside. Does the standard enforce when `p` will be assigned ? (before construction ends or before it begins) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard does not guarantee anything like this.

To fix it you need to have a memory barrier between construction of your object and assigning the pointer so that there is inter-thread happens-before relationship between them:

```
Class* tmp = new Class();
// you need a memory barrier here
p = tmp;
```

In c++11 you use `std::atomic` to introduce memory barriers:

```
std::atomic<Class*> p;
```

And in this case it is better to use `store()` rather than assignment:

```
p.store(tmp, std::memory_order_release);
```

Comment: This is wrong. *In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value
computation of the right and left operands* - [expr.ass]/1

Comment: @Anton: this is what the C++ standard says, now how about the reordering CPU and the way memory is observed from another thread? If sequenced-after meant correct visibility order across threads we wouldn't need atomic in the language.

Comment: Also if my understanding is correct the compiler is still allowed to reorder instructions even across "sequenced before" provided it can guarantee the same result observed in the current thread of execution.

Comment: "Sequenced before" implies "happens before", (see N4140 [intro.multithread]/14). But yes, atomics with acquire-release semantics are needed to extend happens-before relation to another thread (and avoid data race which is UB).

Comment: Would it be more correct to say that inter-thread happens-before is required between the actor and assignment?