# C++ set/get methods synchronization

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, mutex

Lets consider such a class in C++:

```
class CuteClass
{
public:
  int    getFancyInt() const;
  float  getNiceFloat() const;
  string getPerfectString() const;

  void setIntSomething(int something);
  void setInternalState(State newState);
};
```

The instance of this class could be accessed concurrently from several different threads. And then:

All getMethods (getFancyInt, getNiceFloat, getPerfectString) shouldn't block each other. They doesn't change the internal state of the object.

All setMethod (setIntSomething, setInternalState) should:

- block each other - to avoid inconsistent state of object,
- block all getMethods - to avoid returning partially changed data,
- be blocked by all getMethods - to avoid returning partially changed data.

A simple lock_guard with mutex will met all requirements except one - getMethod would then block other getMethods.

What solution would be easy and clean in such scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reader/Writer Locks in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c)

Answer (score 7):

What you are loonking for is a R/W mutex.

You lock it as "READ" in all your getter and "WRITE" in all your setter.

Boost shared_mutex is what you are looking for

[Example for boost shared_mutex (multiple reads/one write)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989795/example-for-boost-shared-mutex-multiple-reads-one-write)

In order to be compatible with your "const" declarations, you need to declare the mutex itself as mutable

Comment: Beginning with C++17, we'll also have `std::shared_mutex`.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) should resolve any concern about partly changed data.

[Edited:] No, it doesn't. If I don't delete this wrong answer it's only for the insightful comments that should be preserved.

Comment: Atomic is a valid solution only in case of internal basic types. 
For complex type or multiples types, you can still have race conditions

Comment: `std::atomic` works for user defined types as well, but might involve a lock.

Comment: This does not address the internal state of the object being consistent when read. See the OP point `block all getMethods - to avoid returning partially changed data`

Comment: `std::atomic` has the wrong granularity for this problem. For example, `setInternalState` may very well atomically modify "fancy int", then atomically modify "fancy float". But that's not enough. You want to lock the *entire* sequence of events, such that clients never see the modification of the int before the modification of the float.