# C++ - synchronization of threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14

I have this problem

```
Foo * foo = new Foo();

void A(){
  foo->a();
}

void B(){
  foo->b();
}

void C(){
  foo->reloadAll();
}
```

Once I enter method C and start reloading foo, I dont want to call A or B. However, A or B can be called together. In that case, I dont want to lock any threads.

How to synchronize this? I can use features provided by C++14. Currently, I am using active waiting (while loo with sleep) on atomic variable, but that is not ideal.

EDIT: Calling A, B, or C in threads is driven by GUI (written in other language), so I have no real threads within C++ app.

Comment: What should happend if A or B already executed when C called?

Comment: @Jeka If A or B is executing, wait until they finish to call C.

Comment: You may consider using a `std::shared_mutex` and call `lock_shared()` for `A` and `B`

Comment: Are you certain you have a multi threading issue ? Virtually all GUI frameworks run in only 1 thread.

Comment: @nos Yes. The UI is using threads in background to call methods and not-blocking UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think best option is [shared_mutex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), method C should use unique lock, but A and B use shared lock, check if it available for you.

Also you can use try_lock_shared to return from A and B if C is locked, instead of waiting.

Comment: Shared_mutex is C++17.

Comment: @MartinPerry - but `std::shared_timed_mutex` is C++14. The timing feature is optional.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a readers-writer problem. A and B needs to lock as readers, and C as a writer. Look here: [Reader/Writer Locks in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c)

Comment: The answer is mostly using boost or old C/C++.

Comment: @MartinPerry: In other words, you want Reader/Writer lock *functionality* avaiable **specifically in C++14**. Why do not formulate your question so (and choose appropriate title)? Currently your question looks like you even don't know about reader-writer lock (as a pattern), so given answer is legitimate and most likely will get the best score.

Answer (score 0):

What about using two [unique locks](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), one for a and one for b. Lock when a/b starts and unlock when a/b ends, respectively, c locks/unlocks both?