# Hand-rolled readers-writers spin lock with priority for readers (write starvation is ok)

Tags: c++, locking, lock-free, stdatomic, spinlock

it is right? is there has any data race?

a read-write lock
write less and read more
write operate not important，it can starve

```
#include<vector>
#include<atomic>

std::vector<int> val;
std::atomic_uint32_t lock;

void Append(int v) {
  uint32_t expect = 0;
  // write lock
  while(!lock.compare_exchange_strong(expect, 1 << 31));
  // do some read
  val.push_back(v);
  // write unlock
  lock.fetch_xor(1 << 31);
}

int Get(size_t i) {
  // read lock
  lock.fetch_add(1);
  while(lock.load() & (1 << 31));
  // do some read
  int v = val[i];
  // read unlock
  lock.fetch_sub(1);
  return v;
}
```

Comment: This isn't lock-free, you're hand-rolling a readers/writers spinlock with busy-waits in both cases.  Looks like it might be ok for correctness, but not efficient if a writer is waiting for long.  C++17 `std::shared_lock` vs. `std::unique_lock` on a `std::mutex` already implements this, but with fallback to a sleep if the lock isn't available.  [Reader/Writer Locks in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/244316)  . (Not sure how it prioritizes, like if it spends extra effort to try to avoid starvation or not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't lock-free of course, you're intentionally hand-rolling a readers/writers spinlock with busy-waits in both cases.  If a writer sleeps forever, no other threads max any progress.

Looks ok to me for correctness, but not efficient if a writer is waiting for long.  (Or if readers are waiting while a writer grows the array with a realloc + copy).  And not even an x86 `_mm_pause()` in the spin-loops, let alone a C++20 `lock.wait()` and `lock.notify_all()` which could let it sleep and have the OS wake up readers when a writer calls notify_all.  (Writers would probably always have to call notify_all, making them more expensive, unless you add extra state that readers update before sleeping.)

C++17 `std::shared_lock` vs. `std::unique_lock` on a `std::mutex` already implements this, but with fallback to a sleep if the lock isn't available.  See *[Reader/Writer Locks in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/244316)*. (Not sure how it prioritizes, like if it spends extra effort to try to avoid starvation or not.  It seems you're intentionally prioritizing reads over writes, which a standard library lock probably doesn't; I'd guess that out of the box they'd be designed to avoid  starvation.)

---

**You could create a container that allowed concurrent append,** with an atomic `fetch_add` incrementing a `write_pos` counter up to a limit, only taking a unique_lock if you need to reallocate.  (Keep that counter in a separate cache line from the pointer to the data, to avoid contention with reads.)  A bit like a lock-free queue in a circular buffer, but much simpler because you're only growing and there's no bounds-checking in the reader.

**If read-side scalability is actually important, you could consider RCU for near-perfect reader concurrency, being truly read-only and not taking any lock.**  If the array isn't too huge to copy, and you don't need to reallocate it too often, that could work well.  Or combine with the previous idea: reserve extra space for atomic growth, so you only need an RCU reallocate when it gets to the end of the size you've reserved.  That can make actual read-copy-update operations rare enough to be usable even with a decent frequency of writes.  (**And readers can still be reading fully wait-free while the copy/update is running**; writers might use a lock to prevent too much wasted work with multiple writers copying at once.)

---

Other minor things about your implementation:

- The operations can be `std::memory_order_acquire` for taking the lock, and `release` for releasing.  That's the same strength C++ `std::mutex` operations have.
- You can use the return value of `.fetch_add` instead of doing a separate seq_cst load.

```
static const uint32_t WRITE_LOCKED = 1UL << 31;
int Get(size_t i) {
  // read lock
  auto lockval = lock.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acquire);
  while(lockval & WRITE_LOCKED){     // wait for any writers to finish
#ifdef __x86_64__
      _mm_pause();        // or boost::detail::sp_thread_pause(), Rust std::hint::spin_loop(), C# SpinOnce() or equivalent.
      // TODO: yield() or sleep() or something after a few iters
      // or lock.wait(lockval)  and have writers call .notify() if there are any readers waiting.
#endif 
      lockval = lock.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  }

  // do some read
  int v = val[i];

  lock.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);    // read unlock
  return v;
}
```

---

Also, **the writer could spin read-only if it doesn't get the lock the first try**, waiting until it looks like it's available before trying another `compare_exchange_weak()`.  That will disrupt readers somewhat less, especially if you put a `pause` or two in its spin loop so it's not spamming attempts.

You could **give the writer a timeout of 500 iterations or something before it sets the bit and waits for all the readers to finish**, preventing new readers from entering.  Except you'd need to change something to be able to detect that: new readers increment the count even if it's write-locked so you can't tell the difference between waiting for old readers to finish vs. new readers waiting to start.  (That's fine for your algorithm, but it doesn't give a writer any way of boosting its priority.)

If you want that, readers would have to work differently somehow.  But making their increment conditional on the high bit might require using a `compare_exchange` retry loop in the reader, instead of just fetch_add, increasing contention between readers.  So maybe there's a more clever way to go about it.