# The reader_writer multithreading problem with locks results in a crash?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to implement sample code for Reader writer problem but the below code is crashing in Reader API. In the code below, `count` is my shared resource between reader and writer.

Here is the exception that throws in gcc compiler :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

What's wrong in the code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
using namespace std;

class ReaderAndWriter
{
    mutex rmu;
    mutex wmu;
    int count = 20;
    int readCount{ 0 };

public:
    

    void Reader()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> readLocker(rmu, std::defer_lock);
        unique_lock<mutex> writeLocker(wmu, std::defer_lock);

        readLocker.lock();
        readCount++;
        if (readCount == 1)
        {
            writeLocker.lock();
        }
        readLocker.unlock();

        cout << "Reader " << count << endl;

        readLocker.lock();
        readCount--;
        if (readCount == 0) 
        {
            writeLocker.unlock();
        }
        readLocker.unlock();
        
    }

    void Writer()
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(wmu); 
        count++;
        cout << "writer " << count << endl;
        locker.unlock();
    }

    void run()
    {
        std::thread reader1(&ReaderAndWriter::Reader, this);
        std::thread reader2(&ReaderAndWriter::Reader, this);
        std::thread reader3(&ReaderAndWriter::Reader, this);

        std::thread writer1(&ReaderAndWriter::Writer, this);
        std::thread writer2(&ReaderAndWriter::Writer, this);

        reader1.join();
        reader2.join();
        reader3.join();

        writer1.join();
        writer2.join();

        cout << "Success" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ReaderAndWriter rw;
    rw.run();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Reader writer locks have default support in C++. See [std::shared_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_lock),  also see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c)
And do not use `using namespace std;` As to your exception that is probably the result of trying to acquire an already locked lock std::mutex and also why std::shared_mutex should be used for reader writer locks.

Comment: _"exception that throws in gcc compiler"_ - that is a runtime error, not a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following possible serial execution order which is permitted by your synchronization:

Suppose reader thread 1 passes through the first `readLocker` section first, incrementing `readCount` to `1` and taking the `writeLocker` lock. Then reader thread 2 passes through the same section, incrementing `readCount` to `2`.

Then thread 1 passes through the second `readLocker` section and doesn't unlock `writeLocker` because `readCount` decrements to `1`, not `0`. Then reader thread 2 passes through the same section and *does* try to unlock `writeLocker` because `readCount` is now decremented to `0`, but since it had never taken the lock, trying that has undefined behavior. An exception is an allowed outcome of that.

---

As pointed out by @SolomonSlow in a comment under this answer, this can be remedied by using a semaphore instead of a mutex for `wmu`. Since C++20 there are semaphores in the standard library. Specifically you could use a [std::binary_semaphore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) initialized to `1`. Then `acquire` can act similar to `lock` and `release` similar to `unlock`, but it wouldn't matter whether the same thread that called `acquire` will call `release`.

As also pointed out in a comment under the question there is already [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) and `std::shared_lock` in the standard library which may be used to manage exclusive as well as shared access without having to implement it with other primitives yourself.

Comment: Good catch! You might point out though that there's an easy fix for this problem in C++20. Use a [_semaphore_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) instead of a mutex for the "write" lock. A binary semaphore is very nearly the same thing as a mutex, except that it is allowed for one thread to "lock" it and a different thread to "unlock" it.  I would not be surprised if OP's code example were adapted from some older example that explicitly used old-school semaphores instead of modern mutexes.

Comment: Thanks std::shared_lock helps for fixing the issue.