Can the Windows API use two mutexes to achieve thread synchronization?
There is a question in my homework: Use mutex to achieve thread synchronization using the Windows API.
I tried using two mutexes to achieve this, but I failed because I found out that a thread cannot use ReleaseMutex() to release a mutex if it has not locked the mutex itself. So, is it possible to achieve thread synchronization using two mutexes?
Here is my code.
My code is intended to print Thread A is running and Thread B is running in order. IOW once thread A has printed a line, the next line should be from thread B, and once thread B as printed a line, the next line should be from thread A.
Like this:
Thread A is running
Thread B is running
Thread A is running
Thread B is running
...

But it actually act like this:
Thread A is running
ReleaseMutex failed. Error: 288
Thread A is running
ReleaseMutex failed. Error: 288
Thread A is running
ReleaseMutex failed. Error: 288
...(Print "Thread A is running ReleaseMutex failed. Error: 288" 10 times, and then block)

In the threadA() function, ReleaseMutex(mutexB) failed with ERROR: 288. Additionally, WaitForSingleObject(mutexA, INFINITE) also encounters the same ERROR: 288, but it does not block. Instead, it runs 10 times and prints 'Thread A is running'. However, threadB is blocked forever.
Please help me resolve this issue!!!!
Is it possible to achieve thread synchronization using two mutexes?
Why does ReleaseMutex() fail?
Why does WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE) not block and instead return a value?
HANDLE mutexA;
HANDLE mutexB;
unsigned __stdcall threadA(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutexA, INFINITE);
        cout << "Thread A is running" << endl;
        if (!ReleaseMutex(mutexB)) {
            cout << "ReleaseMutex failed. Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
unsigned __stdcall threadB(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutexB, INFINITE);
        cout << "Thread B is running" << endl;
        if (!ReleaseMutex(mutexA)) { 
            cout << "ReleaseMutex failed. Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    unsigned threadID1, threadID2;
    mutexA = CreateMutex(nullptr, FALSE, nullptr);// Initialize the mutex and by default
    mutexB = CreateMutex(nullptr, TRUE, nullptr);// Initialize the mutex and lock it immediately
    auto hThreadA = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadA, nullptr, 0, &threadID1);
    auto hThreadB = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadB, nullptr, 0, &threadID2);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadA, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadB, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThreadA);
    CloseHandle(hThreadB);
    CloseHandle(mutexA);
    CloseHandle(mutexB);
    return 0;
}


As for the manual, "The ReleaseMutex function fails if the calling thread does not own the mutex object." mutexB is owned by the main thread. It's unclear why you make it so

why do you think you need two mutexes? You have one shared resource, the output to the console, and you need one mutex to synchronize access to it

The reason I call "mutexB = CreateMutex(nullptr, TRUE, nullptr)" in the main thread is because I want to initialize mutexB with a locked status. This way, I can control the order to print "Thread A is running" first (since mutexB is locked and mutexA is unlocked). After printing "Thread A is running," mutexB will be unlocked  by threadA so that threadB can print "Thread B is running."

Yeah, I know the console should be synchronized if I print to it. But for my homework, I need to use two mutexes to achieve synchronization. So, I simulate a complex calculation by printing "thread is running." For example, thread A generates a number and thread B takes it. It must be done in order.

Please [edit] and confirm that the output should be alternating lines from each thread, IOW once thread A has printed a line, the next line should be from thread B, and once thread B as printed a line, the next line should be from thread A.

The Answer is definitely a "Yes". Only the usage seems to be wrong. For me the use case sound like a Reader/Writer lock situation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c

Ok first of all you are using C++, so don't use all those Windows API calls. For C++ use std::thread (instead of _beginthreadex), std::mutex (instead of CreateMutex) and std::condition_variable (instead of WaitForSingleObject). A reader writer lock can be achieved with std::unique_lock and std::shared_lock (of a std::mutex). std::uniqque_lock and std::shared_lock have an added benefit... if your code has an error the mutex will still be released when your scope exits (lookup see RAII)

If your teacher taught you to use the windows API, then tell him about C++'s native support (since C++11, so it has been around for a while). It allows for much more robust programming in C++

Only the thread that owns a mutex can release it.  What you are attempting to do can be done with a mutex, but not in the way you are trying to do it.  Try something more like this instead:
// alternatively, use std::(j)thread and std::mutex
// instead of the Win32 API...

HANDLE mutex;
char whichThread;

unsigned __stdcall threadA(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        do {
            WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
            if (whichThread != 'A') {
                ReleaseMutex(mutex);
                Sleep(0);
                continue;
            }
        } while (true);
        cout << "Thread A is running" << endl;
        whichThread = 'B';
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall threadB(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        do {
            WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
            if (whichThread != 'B') {
                ReleaseMutex(mutex);
                Sleep(0);
                continue;
            }
        } while (true);
        cout << "Thread B is running" << endl;
        whichThread = 'A';
        ReleaseMutex(mutex);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    mutex = CreateMutex(nullptr, FALSE, nullptr);
    whichThread = 'A';

    unsigned threadID1, threadID2;
    auto hThreadA = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadA, nullptr, 0, &threadID1);
    auto hThreadB = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadB, nullptr, 0, &threadID2);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadA, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadB, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hThreadA);
    CloseHandle(hThreadB);
    CloseHandle(mutex);

    return 0;
}

That being said, I would suggest using either Condition Variables or Event Objects instead, eg:
// alternatively, use std::(j)thread, std::mutex, and
// std::condition_variable instead of the Win32 API ...

CRITICAL_SECTION critSec;
CONDITION_VARIABLE condVarA, condVarB;
char whichThread;

unsigned __stdcall threadA(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&critSec);
        while (whichThread != 'A') {
            SleepConditionVariableCS(&condVarB, &critSec, INFINITE);
        }
        cout << "Thread A is running" << endl;
        whichThread = 'B';
        LeaveCriticalSection(&critSec);
        WakeConditionVariable(&condVarA);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall threadB(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        EnterCriticalSection(&critSec);
        while (whichThread != 'B') {
            SleepConditionVariableCS(&condVarA, &critSec, INFINITE);
        }
        cout << "Thread B is running" << endl;
        whichThread = 'A';
        LeaveCriticalSection(&critSec);
        WakeConditionVariable(&condVarB);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&critSec);
    InitializeConditionVariable(&condVarA);
    InitializeConditionVariable(&condVarB);
    whichThread = 'A';

    unsigned threadID1, threadID2;
    auto hThreadA = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadA, nullptr, 0, &threadID1);
    auto hThreadB = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadB, nullptr, 0, &threadID2);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadA, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadB, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hThreadA);
    CloseHandle(hThreadB);

    DeleteCriticalSection(&critSecA);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&critSecB);

    return 0;
}

Or:
// alternatively, use std::(j)thread, but there is
// no standard C++ replacement for Win32 Events, but
// you can make your own RAII wrapper if needed...

HANDLE hEventA;
HANDLE hEventB;

unsigned __stdcall threadA(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hEventB, INFINITE);
        cout << "Thread A is running" << endl;
        ResetEvent(hEventB);
        SetEvent(hEventA);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned __stdcall threadB(void*) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hEventA, INFINITE);
        cout << "Thread B is running" << endl;
        ResetEvent(hEventA);
        SetEvent(hEventB);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    hEventA = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);
    hEventB = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, TRUE, nullptr);

    unsigned threadID1, threadID2;
    auto hThreadA = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadA, nullptr, 0, &threadID1);
    auto hThreadB = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(nullptr, 0, threadB, nullptr, 0, &threadID2);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadA, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThreadB, INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hThreadA);
    CloseHandle(hThreadB);
    CloseHandle(hEventA);
    CloseHandle(hEventB);

    return 0;
}

